# How to access variables inside string interpolation in a Groovy DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl

I'm building a DSL in Groovy which should allow to use string interpolation inside the DSL:

```
def dsl = """
   def projectName = "test"
   project("${projectName}/123") {
      task {

      }
   }
"""
```

Unfortunately, when using the following code to interpret the above DSL, the Groovy interpreter is not aware of `projectName` (and yields a MissingPropertyException):

```
class ProjectSpec {
    def name

    void task(closure) {
    }
}
binding.project = { name, closure ->
    def project = new ProjectSpec()
    project.name = name
    def code = closure.rehydrate(project, this, this)
    code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    code()
    project
}
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
Script script = shell.parse(dsl)
project = script.run()
println project.name
```

How can I achieve that? I guess I have to defer the evaluation of the GString. Do I have to use an ASTTransformation for this?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug comes from the way you test your dsl. You use a triple double  quotes to define your dsl String : the variable is interpolated here. If you read this variable from a file, you'll see your code works.

Define your dsl String with a triple simple quote (`'''`): it should work.